# Need to search object elements in a LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

I am working on a program which will store objects in a LinkedList, and then search for specific objects in the list by searching the fields of said objects to match them and create prices, but I cannot figure out how to actually complete this task.  I have attached code snippets to see the foundation of what I am doing, and any help would be much appreciated.

```
public class Database {
LinkedList<ProduceItem> list = new LinkedList<ProduceItem>();

public Database() throws FileNotFoundException{
    String name = "PriceList.txt";
    File file = new File(name); //Create file object


    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);  //Create Scanner object to read from file
    String line = null; //String for input

    while(inputFile.hasNextLine()){                                     //While loop to sort through the file
            line = inputFile.nextLine();                                //Read line from file
            if(line.charAt(0) == 'V'){
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
                Vegtable veg = new Vegtable();
                tokenizer.nextToken();                                  //Burn first token to eliminate identifier
                veg.setCode(tokenizer.nextToken());
                veg.setName(tokenizer.nextToken());
                veg.setPrice(Float.parseFloat(tokenizer.nextToken()));
                list.add(veg);
            }
            else{
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
                Fruit fru = new Fruit();
                tokenizer.nextToken();
                fru.setCode(tokenizer.nextToken());
                fru.setName(tokenizer.nextToken());
                fru.setPrice(Float.parseFloat(tokenizer.nextToken()));
                list.add(fru);

            }
    }   
    inputFile.close();
}
```

}

Comment: what are the tasks that you need to do exactly?

Comment: I need to search each fruit or vegetable object in the list using a String name or String code for a matching name or code, each of which have accessor and mutator methods.  Once found I have code in place that can handle the calculations I need to make, I just cant figure out how to search each objects fields using the given strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
for(ProduceItem item : list) {

   if(item.name.equals(searchKey) {
      //perform calculations or display to screen here
   }

}
```

Comment: That seems to work, but I would like to understand more about how it works, I understand the if statement but I dont understand the parameters within the for loop.  Can you elaborate a little please?  Thank you very much!

Comment: sure, the for-loop will provide one item at a time (this is a feature of the LinkedList). An alternative is to use for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { ProduceItem item = list.at(i) ... }

Comment: Thank you very much you have been a huge help!